ClickOnce issues opening application
Occasionally, several users (myself included) face an issue when attempting to run one of our ClickOnce applications. Our organization has around a dozen ClickOnce apps, but the problem seems to be isolated to one specific application.
When running the app via Setup.exe, nothing will happen. The app doesn't open, and the PC continues operating normally - as if the app was never opened. This appears to be irregular, some weeks it will work fine every day, other weeks it will occur every day, and every combination in between.
We have found two temporary solutions:

Uninstall the application and reinstall using setup.exe
Run a different ClickOnce application, then run the troubled application

Based on these workarounds, it seems the issue might be related to the application's cache, although I haven’t been able to confirm this.
It presents similarly to this post. However, its spread across most of our organization and does not affect other ClickOnce apps.
So I believe an error was made when creating it, but I'm unsure where the error is.

Does ClickOnce application won't start lead you anywhere useful?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
